# Is it possible to change the text of a ListView item when date is set?

Tags: android

I have a ListView showing options choose date, choose time. I have an inner class implementing OnDateSetListener, and OnTimeSetListener.

Is there any way to update the items after date or time was set?

```
listViewOptions = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_options);
String[] options = new String[]{"Choose date...", "Choose time..."};
    ArrayAdapter<String> optionsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.simple_list_item,
            options
    );
    listViewOptions.setAdapter(optionsAdapter);
    listViewOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    //show date picker
                    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(
                            context,
                            new MyListener(),
                            date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    );
                    datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(date.getTimeInMillis());
                    datePicker.show();
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(
                            context,
                            new MyListener(),
                            date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                            date.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                            false
                    );
                    timePicker.show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

the inner class:

```
private class MyListener implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        //change text of the "choose date..." item
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        //change text of the "choose time..." item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom adapter an make a public method `refill(... Insert new data...)` and inside it, change your dataset and after you have done that, call `notifyDataSetChanged();` so that ListView refreshes the new data.

See this website for a lot of explanation and examples on how to implement a custom listview adapter

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html